# Method for FacebookLogin is not defined

Tags: dart, flutter, facebook-login

I have been struggling with this for a while guys. 
My flutter_facebook_package is successfully hooked up with the app, but for some reason `fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions` shows:

```
[dart] The method 'logInWithReadPermissions' isn't defined for the class 'FacebookLogin'
```

Did I miss anything with getting the package or importing something more?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//facebook signUp
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class FacebookLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FacebookLoginState createState() => _FacebookLoginState();
}

class _FacebookLoginState extends State<FacebookLogin> {

  FacebookLogin fbLogin = new FacebookLogin();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Container(
        height: 40.0,
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 112, 166),
          elevation: 7.0,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']).then((result) {
                switch(result.status) {
                  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithFacebook(
                    accessToken: result.accessToken.token
                  ).then((signedInUser) {
                    print('Sighned in as ${signedInUser.displayName}');
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                  }).catchError((e) {
                    print(e);
                  });
                }
              })
              .catchError((e) {
                print(e);
              });
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Log in with facebook',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Monserrat'
                )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks up `flutter_facebook_login` in the `.packages` file and delete the directory listed there (remove `lib/` from the path) and run `flutter packages get` again. It looks like the downloaded cached package got corrupted.

Comment: Hmm, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using your own class `class FacebookLogin` that shadows the class from

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
```

Rename your widget class and it will work.

Alternatively you can use

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart' as fl;
...
fl.FacebookLogin fbLogin = new fl.FacebookLogin();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That did it!

Comment: This did it. But can anyone tell me why the normal import was creating issues?

Comment: @KarunShrestha I don't understand what's unclear. You can't have 2 classes with the same name in the same scope because it's not clear which one you are referring to when you use the name. The prefix allows to distinguish.

Answer (score 18):

Just replace `fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);`
with `fbLogin.logIn(['email']);`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `flutter_facebook_login` **3.0.0**, they have removed deprecated method `loginWithPublishPermissions` and renamed `loginWithReadPermission` to `login`.

Comment: Actually, they renamed it to `logIn()`, mind the capital I. Check @Touhid Sunny's answer bellow.

Answer (score 2):

It's resolved in package `flutter_facebook_login` version 3.0.0 as they replaced `logInwithReadPermissions()` with `logIn()`. Just use `logIn()` instead. My problem was solved by that.

Answer (score 0):

follow as below

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart' as fl;
class _FacebookLoginState extends State {

FacebookLogin fbLogin = new FacebookLogin();

...


...

...

fl.logInwithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']).then(result) // this is where you have to modify and everything remains same

if then also problem persists then instead of fl.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']).then(result) follow as below

fl.logIn(['email', 'public_profile']).then(result)
```